# Eclipse: Search java files from a specific author

Tags: java, eclipse, author, file-search

Is there a way we may search files from a specific author(by looking at the value provided in `@author` annotation) in Eclipse IDE or otherwise? It would be excellent if part matches are supported (e.g. - "@author Tom Cruise" should be a match for search "cru").

Comment: Eclipse doesn't provide a regex search that could be done on each file of the project ? (can't check, don't have it on this workstation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'Search > File...'

On the File dialog enter something like `@author*cru` for the 'Containing text' to match an @author and also containing by 'cru'

Enter `*.java` in the 'File name patterns'

Click 'Workspace' in the 'Scope' section.

You can also choose to use a regular expression in the 'Containing text' section by selecting the 'Regular expression' check box.

Answer (score 0):

Check this tool: https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/. It finds every thing you want, just define the regex and the file types you want to be scanned.
Text: @author Tom Cruise
File: *.java